# Not sure how to interpret some algebra for a DE

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm taking vector calculus and going through my notes I came across this which I paid no mind at the time; In finding a regular singular point for a D.E. my instructor made the following leap:

$$2x^2y"-xy'+(x-5)y=0\hspace{0.5cm}\Rightarrow\hspace{0.5cm} y"+\frac{2}xy'+ \frac{x^2-2}2y=0$$

And now, looking over it at home, I have no idea what happened here. Can someone explain?

Comment: does not seem reasonable to me. are you sure you transcribed it right?

Comment: @mathreadler I'm positive I copied it accurately, the coefficients of the first eq. show up multiple times throughout. and he uses coefficients of the second to show that x=0 is a reg. sing. point. This wouldn't be the first time my prof has had a brain fart though...

Comment: The lack of context makes it probably easier for one of your classmates to explain it than for us who don't know any more than you have written here.

Comment: @mathreadler I was afraid of as much. Thanks for taking the time however :)